# HTML output provided to a PHP file

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

I have an HTML form, when clicked Submit, gives me an output in JSON format with the help of

```
$('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
```

My HTML form has `action="filename.php"`* and its method as **post**

Now I want to send/read these values in a PHP file and should be able to perform operations on them. Like, print them on screen (Echo) or insert them into database.

Please help on how to get the values in readable/accessible format in my php file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah please check out [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Javascript is not needed in this case (at least, with the details currently provided in the question). Also, this is a very basic problem that can easily be solved through a quick Google search. Search for PHP form, PHP POST, PHP GET

Comment: `$.post('url here', post data here eg: { id : 12 }, function(returnedPage) { this is the callback function eg: alert(returnedPage); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In filename.php

```
$formData = json_decode($_POST['fieldname']);
```

will decode the json string from your form post into a PHP object.  If you want an array pass `true` as the second param to the json_decode method

You'll need to replace `fieldname` with the attribute name from your HTML / Javascript that holds the json data.

Comment: <?php 
echo json_decode($_GET['Fname']);
?>this is working.. but when I do an echo, I see nothing.

Comment: you can't `echo` an array or object, as such.  If you want to see if for debugging then `var_dump` it.  If you want to output it on the page you need to loop over it and echo each node

Comment: when I do echo$_GET['Fname'], I see the value entered in my HTML form

Comment: Thats because before you do the json_decode() call you have a JSON string, which can be echo'd

Comment: hmm makes sense... but when I do var_dump, I see "null" there.

Comment: if you are getting null, then the json_decode has not been able to decode the string.  Can you post the actual json string you get in your php (the one if you echo $_GET['Fname'];)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29120/discussion-between-fullybaked-and-user1397891)

Comment: Yes. it's a simple string - "Myname"

Answer (score 0):

You can post the variables as normal (no JQuery serialization to JSON) and then you can access the posted variables via the `$_POST` variable in `filename.php`.